# Javafx/CSS White not Displaying Correctly Against Black Background

Tags: css, javafx

I have a Javafx interface with white text and a black background, however the white seems REALLY dim, below is the result of my CSS and my code.[image]As you can see there is barely any difference between the white and black even though I explicitly set it to white. Below is the CSS:

```
#KeyValues{
    -fx-background-color:black;
}
#ScienceLabel{
    -fx-font-color:white;
}
#GoldLabel{
    -fx-font-color:white;
}
```

Just to note KeyValues is an HBox and the labels are well...labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
-fx-text-fill:white;
```

Instead of:

```
-fx-font-color:white;
```